# C++ capture value of all pointer wrappers in variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

```
std::deque<std::function<std::string()>> log_queue;

void store_log(T&& t, U&&... u) const
{
    log_queue.push_back(
        [t, u...]() {
            return format_log(t, u...));
        });
    
    if (log_queue.size() > 1000)
    {
        log_queue.pop_front();
    }
}
```

I use the above function to store the latest 1000 log messages in a circular buffer and print the contents of log_queue when an issue happens in my developing environment.

There is a problem with this approach. Some of the arguments (U...) are **pointer wrappers**.
So when I print log_queue  contents, I see the **last updated value** for these pointers instead of the value it had when the store_log function was called. I can solve this issue by storing std::string instead of the lambda, but that is very very expensive (I want to stringify only the last 1000 logs). So instead I would like to store the value contained by the pointer wrappers
instead of the pointer wrapper itself. Is there any easy way?

**Pointer wrapper details:**

```
template <typename T>
class ptr_wrapper
{
    T* t = nullptr;
    int ref_count = 0; 
    // constructors and destructors
    // functions for updating ref_count whenevr this object is copies/moved etc
};
```

};

Comment: What if you want to log something like `pointer_wrapper<UncopyableType>`?

Comment: That is a good point. Currently, everything is copyable, so no issues

Comment: By pointer wrappers you really just mean that `t,u` are pointers and you want to dereference them? Or do you have a real wrapper? If so, post its API please.

Comment: @Quimby I have updated the question as per suggestion. Please let me know in case you need anything else.

Comment: Are you limited to C++17? There's a nice C++20 solution.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah c++-17 is the max I can get to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might apply transformation before the capture:

```
void store_log(T&& t, Us&&... us) const
{
    log_queue.push_back(
        [tup = std::make_tuple(value(t), value(us)...)]() {
            return std::apply([](const auto&... args){ format_log(args...), tup));
        });
    
    if (log_queue.size() > 1000)
    {
        log_queue.pop_front();
    }
}
```

with

```
template <typename T>
const T& value(const T& value) { return value; }

template <typename T>
std::optional<T> value(const ptr_wrapper<T>& wrapper) {
    if (wrapper.t) return *wrapper.t;
    return {};
}

// other overloads possible to do deep copy, instead of keeping reference
// ...
```

C++14's syntax; in C++11, you have to declare the variable before the lambda.